# Delete multiple tables using foreign Key - ADO.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to DELETE records in multiple tables with ADO.NET.

I want to DELETE a Old record into a table. It has a foreign key mapped to a different table. tables:

[image]

Example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Date WHERE Date < DATEADD(Day,-10 , getdate())";
```

But this code not worked and I want to be removed from all related tables.

How can I Delete values into these tables at one time?

Comment: Oh, well the relationship is meaningless here. However use the same where clause on the T_Name table

Comment: no relationship ?!!!  How do i use T_Name table ?

Comment: Do you only want this when you delete from the code or do you want this for the foreign key? If it is the second case, then use ON DELETE CASCADE with your foreign key. Check this: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: Delete entries from T_Name table like 

Delete from T_Name where date < dateadd(day, -10, getdate()) 

then delete it from Date table.

Because Date table is having reference to T_Name table. so we delete directly from Date table some reference will be there T_Name table, which will not allow the row to be deleted.